# Sending email using SMTP protocol and boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, network-programming, smtp

I am trying to send an email using the SMTP protocol and boost libraries
but for some reason i am unable to connect to the hotmail smtp server and send email to myself..

this is my code:
what am i doing wrong?

```
    DNS_RECORD* ppQueryResultsSet = NULL;

    // dns mx lookup
    DnsQuery(L"hotmail.com", DNS_TYPE_MX, DNS_QUERY_STANDARD, NULL, &ppQueryResultsSet, NULL);

    if (ppQueryResultsSet == NULL)
        return false;

    // i am getting the mx servers (i.e: mx3.hotmail.com)
    wcout << "MX Host name: " << ppQueryResultsSet->Data.MX.pNameExchange << endl;
    DnsRecordListFree(ppQueryResultsSet, DnsFreeRecordList);

    string host_name = String_Convertion::WStringToString(ppQueryResultsSet->Data.MX.pNameExchange);

    // setting up socket connection
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(host_name, "25");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query), end;
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);

    // connecting to the server
    boost::system::error_code error_code_connect;
    boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator, end, error_code_connect);
    if (error_code_connect)
    {
        cout << "Error connecting to SMTP Server" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    boost::system::error_code error;
    std::string temp_buf;
    boost::array<char, 128> buf;
    size_t len;

    // settings the packets to send
    list<string> packets;
    packets.push_back("HELO");
    packets.push_back("MAIL FROM: xxx@xxx.xxx");
    packets.push_back("VRFY xxx@xxx.xxx");
    packets.push_back("RCPT TO: x@hotmail.com"); 
    packets.push_back("DATA");
    packets.push_back("Subject: subject!");
    packets.push_back("hi how are you doing?.");
    packets.push_back("QUIT");
    list<string>::iterator it;
    // iterating to send the packets
    for (it = packets.begin(); it != packets.end(); it++)
    {
        socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(*it+"\r\n"));
        len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
        temp_buf = buf.data();
        temp_buf = temp_buf.substr(0, len);
        cout << temp_buf << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any SMTP server which answers to `VRFY` commands?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read up a bit on how `boost:asio` works.  Essentially, you are creating a service, but never calling `run()`.  Look at the chat sample [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/chat_client.cpp), and note that it spawns a thread exclusively to perform work:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not withstanding that there may be other problems, you need an extra `\r\n` between the headers of your message and the body.

You also need to correctly terminate the `DATA` portion by sending a line just containing  `.\r\n`